# Invoke WCF Service from Hybrid app using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: apache, visual-studio-cordova

I am creating an Hybrid app using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova, could you please help me on how to invoke WCF Service (.svc) in Hybrid app.

Thanks,
Malli

Comment: Refer this SO post on consuming WCF service from phonegap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420683/upload-image-using-phonegap-to-net-wcf-rest-service